# Allowing a Lambda function to exclusively put objects into an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-lambda, policy

My current S3 bucket policy enables `s3:getObject` and `s3:putObject` globally and I am trying to restrict that by specifying a bucket policy.

While `s3:getObject` is safe, I would like to restrict access to `s3:putObject` only to a particular AWS Lambda function.

The function gets triggered anonymously via a HTTP request to CloudFront, so there is no AWS user involved.

How to restrict the access via the Lambda's ARN identifier?

Current policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:getObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:putObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all that was required was to create an access policy for Lambda. There are predefined ones, like `lambda_basic_execution`.

The role config can be found in the AWS console inside:

`Lambda > Functions > {name} > Roles`
`IAM > Roles`

Here is a specific config that helped me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I read your original question correctly, you cannot restrict who/what writes to that S3 bucket simply by creating an IAM role for your Lambda function. All that does is restrict what the Lambda function can do. If you want the Lambda function, and only the Lambda function, to be able to write to that bucket then you need something more (e.g. launch the Lambda in a VPC and modify the S3 bucket policy to restrict access to that VPC).

Comment: After removing the `"Action": "s3:putObject",` Statement I from the bucket policy I am not able to anonymously write into the bucket anymore (only when logged as the owner). Adding the `"Action": "s3:PutObject",` into the Lambda's IAM policy allows it to write into the bucket. That's what I originally wanted, why would I need more?